# Can't control Wordpress Addresses from admin panel

Tags: redirect, htaccess, site-url

I have already created several sites in WordPress and I have always been able to manage the link of my site with or without https and with or without www through the settings in options > general, as you can see here:

[image: Site Settings]

Lately, I have to use a plugin to force https and I've even added code to the `.htaccess` file to redirect to "non-www". However, this `.htaccess` file loses those changes that I make very often (I do not know why).

I would like to know, first of all, if it is possible to manage this type of settings again through the admin panel of my WordPress. If it is not possible, I would like to know why and what is different for this particular site cannot control these settings in the admin panel (because I have already managed to do so in others).

Secondly, if this is not possible, I would like a permanent solution to redirect from `www.example.com` to `example.com` since I already have a plugin to force https.

Comment: What do you see when you go to Settings > General? Are WordPress address and Site address options not there? Have you [set values in the `wp-config` file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WP_SITEURL) or elsewhere for this site, which will disable those options? Also- any code you add to the htaccess file that you don't want overwritten has to go outside of the `#begin` and `#end WordPress` tags that it inserts in the file.

Comment: Hi Milo, thank you so much for answering!
No, the options are there, as you can see in the first screenshot. I have not added those values in wp-config because I would like to manage my WordPress addresses from within the wp-admin panel...

About the last tip to use htaccess maybe I was making that mistake, however, firstly I would like to understand I in this specific website I can't manage the addresses just by changing them. I can't find anything wrong about it. In other wordpress websites I just add the "https" and remove the "www" and the url changes with no problem